# Rails admin: How add helpers and use view helpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-admin

I'm trying to format some currency prices to show in list of Rails Admin.

I tried to define a helper in two ways `app/helpers/rails_admin.rb`:

```rb
module RailsAdmin
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper

  def price_mask_real(price)
    number_to_currency(price, unit: 'R$', separator: ',', delimiter: '.')
  end
end
```

AND

```rb
module RailsAdmin::ViewsHelper
  include ApplicationHelper
end
```

Having now the helper in application like:

```rb
module ApplicationHelper
  def price_mask_real(price)
    number_to_currency(price, unit: 'R$', separator: ',', delimiter: '.')
  end
end
```

And in `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb`

```rb
list do
  configure :price do
    price_mask_real(:price)
  end
end
```

But Rails Admin can't find the helper:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails 3. How to add a helper that ActiveAdmin will use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673112/rails-3-how-to-add-a-helper-that-activeadmin-will-use)

Comment: I tried what they said and the problem still `undefined method `price_mask_real' for #<RailsAdmin::Config::Fields::Types::Decimal:0x0000558784d79298>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to make rails_admin controllers inherit the class that has

```
include ApplicationHelper
```

Most of the time that is the `ApplicationController`

In that case adding this line to the rails admin initializer config file would do it

```
# config/initializers/rails_admin.rb
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.parent_controller = '::ApplicationController'
end
```

Comment: added this and still `undefined method 'price_mask_real' for #<RailsAdmin::Config::Fields::Types::Decimal:0x000055ab9d7318d0>`

Comment: Hey Guilhermo, do you know how to solve this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63726527/rails-admin-how-to-hide-active-storage-models