# Rails Admin: How to Hide Active Storage models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin, rails-activestorage

I'm using Active Storage and Cloudinary to store some images of one of my models, but after add this the Active Storage started to appear in Rails Admin in a navigation tab dedicated to it:

[image]

And its models in Dashboard:

[image]

I would to like to remove both. I tried these things without sucess:

Starting by trying to declare only the models I want to be present

```rb
config.included_models = [User, Notebook, Tag, Category, Part]
```

But since i'm using attachments in Notebook it complains:

[image]

Then I tried to just hide:

```rb
config.model 'ActiveStorage' do
 list do
  visible false
 end
 navigation do
  visible false
 end
end
```

Also with the models directly

```rb
config.model 'Attachment' do
 list do
  visible false
 end
 navigation do
  visible false
 end
end

config.model 'Blob' do
 list do
  visible false
 end
 navigation do
  visible false
 end
end
```

Or maybe it's possible to do something factoring like

```rb
ActiveStorage::Base.descendants.each do |imodel|
 config.model "#{imodel.name}" do
   visible false
 end
end
```

As we can do with ActiveRecord as shown in [Creating a Custom Field Factory](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Fields#creating-a-custom-field-factory) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `rails_admin.rb` add the following:

```
config.model 'ActiveStorage::Blob' do
  visible false
end
```

since the Blob class comes from ActiveStorage.

The same applies for the Attachment class.

Comment: HAHA I knew I had to references ActiveStorage I just didn't knew how! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it, it needs to be

```
config.model 'Blob' do
 visible false
end
```

Option b)
On the model itself blob.rb

```
class Blob < ApplicationRecord
  rails_admin do
    visible false
  end
end
```

Comment: I've already tried that. It did not worked. :(
I've also tried 'active_storage_blobs' which is the actual table name.

Comment: It seems you can directly refeer to models by `config.model ModelName` for Active Record Models. Maybe it needs some configuration to make a statement related to Active Storage Models...

Comment: I've tried with the Option B but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 6 I do the following

```rb
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.model 'ActiveStorage::Blob' do
    visible false
  end

  config.model 'ActiveStorage::Attachment' do
    visible false
  end

  config.model 'ActiveStorage::VariantRecord' do
    visible false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In rails 6 I used

```
config.excluded_models = %w[ActiveStorage::Blob ActiveStorage::Attachment ActiveStorage::VariantRecord]
```